# Django mongodb auth with mongoengine error

Tags: python, django, mongodb, authentication, mongoengine

I try to extend basic user document from mongo and normally i would do it like this:

```
from mongoengine.django.auth import User

class Account(User):
    field1=something1
    field2=something2
```

etc.

Somehow i just can't import django.auth from mongoengine.
It just says: 
ImportError: No module named django.auth

And actually it worked for me couple of months ago and that is why i am confused.

I have installed django, and then according to the docs: django-nonrel, djangotoolbox, mongodb engine all in virtual env.

Then i've installed mongoengine using pip.

In settings.py i also included in installed apps `'mongoengine'` and it worked fine, but i still can't import django.auth.

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Just for anyone that will be struggling with this.

django.auth or even mongoengine.django is not included in mongoengine 0.10 as it seems but it is in 0.9 so i downgraded it.

Also to get connection working properly i needed to update pymongo from 2.7.1 to 2.8.1 and now it all works fine.